# What's the easiest way to read several ints from stdin if it's ok to fail?

Tags: rust

Suppose I expect a line with 3 integers from stdin. What's the easiest way to read and parse them? What's the Rust equivalent of `a, b, c = map(int, input().split())` in Python or `scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);` in C?

The best way I came up with was something like:

```
let mut line = String::new();
io::stdin().read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
let parts: Vec<&str> = line.split_whitespace().collect();
let a: i32 = parts[0].parse().unwrap();
let b: i32 = parts[1].parse().unwrap();
let c: i32 = parts[2].parse().unwrap();
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`text_io`](https://crates.io/crates/text_io) for this:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate text_io;

fn main() {
    // reads until a whitespace is encountered
    let a: i32 = read!();
    let b: i32 = read!();
    let c: i32 = read!();
}
```

---

`text_io` `0.1.3` also supports a `scan!` macro:

```
let (a, b, c): (i32, i32, i32);
scan!("{}, {}, {}\n", a, b, c);
```

---

in case you want to read from a file or some other source, you can also use both macros on any type that implements `Iterator<Item=u8>`:

```
use std::io::Read;
let mut file = std::fs::File::open("text.txt").unwrap()
                                              .bytes()
                                              .map(Result::unwrap);
let x: i32 = read!("{}\n", file);
```

or

```
let (x, y, z): (i32, i32, i32);
scan!(file => "{}, {}: {}", x, y, z);
```

---

You can leave off the `: i32`s if the compiler can infer those types from context.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of `text_io`.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`scan-rules`](https://crates.io/crates/scan-rules) for this:

````rust
/*!
Add this to your `Cargo.toml`, or just run with `cargo script`:

```cargo
[dependencies]
scan-rules = "0.1.1"
```
*/
#[macro_use] extern crate scan_rules;

fn main() {
    print!("Enter 3 ints: ");
    readln! {
        (let a: i32, let b: i32, let c: i32) => {
            println!("a, b, c: {}, {}, {}", a, b, c);
        }
    }
}
````

If you want to do something a little more involved, you can use multiple rules and type inference, and specify what to do if the input doesn't match any of the rules given (by default it `panic!`s):

```
readln! {
    // Space-separated ints
    (let a: i32, let b: i32, let c: i32) => {
        println!("a b c: {} {} {}", a, b, c);
    },

    // Comma-separated ints, using inference.
    (let a, ",", let b, ",", let c) => {
        let a: i32 = a;
        let b: i32 = b;
        let c: i32 = c;
        println!("a, b, c: {}, {}, {}", a, b, c);
    },

    // Comma-separated list of *between* 1 and 3 integers.
    ([let ns: i32],{1,3}) => {
        println!("ns: {:?}", ns);
    },

    // Fallback if none of the above match.
    (..line) => {
        println!("Invalid input: {:?}", line);
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of `scan-rules`.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered you can use [`split_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.split_whitespace) to put the integers in the string into an iterator. Then you unwrap it out of  [`std::option::Option<&str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) using `unwrap()`. After parsing the `&str` using [`parse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) and unwrapping its result using `unwrap()`, you have an integer if you have specified the type of variable using `variable_name: i32 = ...`:

```rust
let mut numbers = String::new();
io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut numbers)
    .ok()
    .expect("read error");
let mut iter = numbers.split_whitespace();
let mut x: i32 = iter.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
let mut y: i32 = iter.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
let mut n: i32 = iter.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
println!("{},{},{}", x, y, n);
```