# What is the most efficient way of taking a number of integer user inputs and storing it in a Vec<i32>?

Tags: rust

I was trying to use rust for competitive coding and I was wondering what is the most efficient way of storing user input in a Vec. I have come up with a method but I am afraid that it is slow and redundant.

Here is my code:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
  let mut input = String::new();
  io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("cant read line");
  let input:Vec<&str> = input.split(" ").collect();
  let input:Vec<String> = input.iter().map(|x| x.to_string()).collect();
  let input:Vec<i32> = input.iter().map(|x| x.trim().parse().unwrap()).collect();
  println!("{:?}", input);
}
```

PS: I am new to rust.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the easiest way to read several ints from stdin if it's ok to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860264/whats-the-easiest-way-to-read-several-ints-from-stdin-if-its-ok-to-fail)

Comment: @E_net4standswithUkraine The linked question asks about simplest way and this question asks about the most performant way.

Comment: @E_net4standswithUkraine thanks for suggesting, but in the question that you suggested the person who asked clearly said that the number of inputs that they were expecting were known at compile time. Most examples handle a case of three integers and most of the answers use some external crate. I don't know the number of inputs during compile time as in most competitive coding question the input size is known only during the runtime.

Comment: Probably: `let input = input.trim().split (" ").map (|x| x.parse().unwrap()).collect::<Vec<i32>>()` although as with all performance-related questions, you should [measure](https://crates.io/crates/criterion) all candidate solutions to confirm.

Comment: What are your requirements on error handling? Does the solution need to handle invalid inputs gracefully, or is it ok for it to simply panic, or behave in an undefined way? It's usually possible to improve performance if you don't need to handle errors.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I don't need to handle errors, simply panicking would be more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see those ways of improving performance of the code:

1. Although not really relevant for `std::io::stdin()`, `std::io::BufReader` may have great effect for reading e.g. from `std::fs::File`. Buffer capacity can also matter.
2. Using locked stdin: `let si = std::io::stdin(); let si = si.locked();`
3. Avoiding allocations by keeping vectors around and using `extend_from_iter` instead of `collect`, if the code reads multiple line (unlike in the sample you posted in the question).
4. Maybe avoiding temporary vectors alltogether and just chaining `Iterator` operations together. Or using a loop like `for line in input.split(...) { ... }`. It may affect performance in both ways - you need to experiment to find out.
5. Avoiding `to_string()` and just storing reference to input buffer (which can also be used to `parse()` into `i32`. Note that this may invite famous Rust borrowing and lifetimes complexity.
6. Maybe finding some fast SIMD-enhanced string to int parser instead of libstd's `parse()`.
7. Maybe streaming the result to algorithm instead of collecting everything to a `Vec` first. This can be beneficial especially if multiple threads can be used. For performance, you would still likely need to send data in chunks, not by one single `i32`.

Comment: (3) and (4) are definitely the most critical here, you should be able to parse everything with no allocation other than the `input` buffer, and possibly resizing of the target `Vec` (depending on what you actually need, it would be better if you kept the iterator if that's possible as you say in (7)). A mitigation option would be to use a stack-allocated vector of some sort (or load the numbers you parse into an on-stack array, though that requires doing your own bookkeeping of the number of values you found).

Comment: Sometimes `BufReader` (or analogue) is the most critical element (maybe not in this case, but in general when reading input in competitive programming), as it economizes not just CPU cycles, but also system calls.

Comment: Note that `stdin` already uses buffered reading, and locks the mutex for each operation → so long as there is only one line to read, `stdin().read_line(…)` should already be optimal.

Comment: Indeed, I checked that it reads in blocks of 8192 bytes even if I read `std::io::stdin()` byte by byte. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there are some changes you can make that will make your code more precise, simple and faster.

A better code :

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
  let mut input = String::new();
  io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

  let input: Vec<i32> = input.split_whitespace().map(|x| x.parse().unwrap()).collect();

  println!("{:?}", input);
}
```

### Explanation

1. The `input.split_whitespace()` returns an iterator containing elements that are seperated by any kind of whitespace including line breaks. This saves the time used in spliting by just one whitespace `input.split(" ")` and iterating over again with a `.trim()` method on each string slice to remove any surronding whitespaces.
   (You can also checkout `input.split_ascii_whitespace()`, if you want to restrict the split over ascii whitespaces).
2. There was no need for the code `input.iter().map(|x| x.to_string()).collect()`, since you can call also call a `.trim()` method on a string slice.

This saves some time in both the runtime and coding process, since the `.collect()` method is only used once and there was just one iteration.